# Add & delete item from LinearLayout using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

[image: Screenshot of what I am making]

I am doing bubble display of selected contacts. Each telephone bubble is a LinearLayout, which contains ImageView and TextView. These bubbles are then displayed in another LinearLayout which is child of HorizontalScrollView.

It child/parent tree looks like this:

```
 - HorizontalScrollView
 |- LinearLayout (id="@+id/telField")
  |- LinearLayout (id="@+id/telBox")  <- is programmatically added to parent
   |- TextView (id="@+id/telNumber")
   |- ImageView (id="@+id/delNumber")
```

In my .java class I call this method to display "telBox" LinearLayout in "telField" LinearLayout:

```
public void createAdapter() {
    telList = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.text_buble, R.id.telNumber, telNumList);
    telField = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.telField);

    telField.removeAllViews();
    final int adapterCount = telNumList.size();

    for (ik = 0; ik < adapterCount; ik++) {
        final View item = telList.getView(ik, null, null);
        telField.addView(item);

        item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                telField.removeView(item);
                telNumList.remove(ik-1);
                telList.notifyDataSetChanged();
                refresh();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Method `refresh();` – is custom method which helps to "reload" Activity: it gets App values, refreshes warning ImageViews and **cals createAdapter() method**.

Big button "SELECT" calls an Intent which returns a selected phone number from a contacts book. I call this code to update my LinearLayout with id "telField":

```
telNumList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
createAdapter();
```

Problem I face is:

> After I click on LinearLayout with id "telNumber" it one by one deletes every bubble (no matter which I clicked) until it reaches first added bubble. It also crashes 50/50 when reaches first added element, I have not figured out a dependency. The error it returns is "out of bounds error", so I think it is connected with `ik - 1` line.

My question is: How do I better construct my ArrayAdapter?

Comment: a horizontal recyclerview will be better option as compared to linear layout in my opinion as add delete will be easier

Comment: The view you're showing in the preview is perfectly realisable with tokenAutoComplete lib: https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your for loop, write these line of code:

```
for (ik = 0; ik < adapterCount; ik++) {

    final View item = telList.getView(ik, null, null);
    item.setTag(ik);
    telField.addView(item);

    item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int index = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            telNumList.remove(index);
            refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are trying to remove the view by `ik` which is getting change continuously because of which your coding is removing last view I have modified your code as given below

```
for (ik = 0; ik < adapterCount; ik++) {
        final int position=ik;
        final View item = telList.getView(ik, null, null);
        telField.addView(item);

        item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                telField.removeView(item);
                telNumList.remove(position);
                telList.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //refresh();
                createAdapter();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here `position` will help you to remove the particular view which you want to remove. I hope this is what you are asking for.

Comment: You solution works, thank you! I do appreciate your help! Unfortunately Rahul Sharma was faster :)

Comment: Not an issue. Thanks for the up vote. I hope it will be helpful to some else who will find it more easy.